# Раскрасить текст в терминале по hex-значению цвета такому как #4e1747

Tags: python, python-3.x

Добрый день!

Нужно в консоль вывести цветной блок. Есть такой код:

```
from termcolor import colored
...
print (colored('\u2588\u2588\', '#%s' %(color)))
```

Где color это hex-значение цвета, но похоже, что termcolor не умеет в hex 
Также пытался с модулем colored (который умеет распознавать hex)

```
import colored
color_t = fg('#'+color)
```

Но появляется ошибка `KeyError: '#4e1747'` (случайный цвет)
как быть?

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Print in terminal with colors using Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/287871/4279)

Comment: похожий вопрос: [ANSI Color Specific RGB Sequence Bash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15682537/4279)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`colored` модуль](https://github.com/dslackw/colored/blob/master/colored/hex.py) поддерживает только 256 xterm цветов для терминала (`\x1b[38;5;` ANSI escape). Поэтому вы получаете `KeyError`, если цвет в эту таблицу не входит.

Возможны два варианта: либо пытаться приближённый цвет показывать либо воспользоваться функциональностью, которая позволяет миллион цветов показать.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

message = 'some string'
hex_color = '#4e1747'
r, g, b = [int(hex_color[i:i+2], 16) for i in range(1, len(hex_color), 2)]
print("\x1b[38;2;{r};{g};{b}m{message}\x1b[0m".format(**vars()))
```

Это работает на моей Ubuntu системе в gnome-terminal и в виртуальных консолях (<kbd>Ctrl+Alt+Fd</kbd>).

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте это - https://pypi.python.org/pypi/colorama

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для ваших нужд вполне может сгодиться.

Comment: Проблема в том, что цветов у меня от #000000 до #ffffff, и заранее цвет не знаю.